# Dynamically disable a span with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am following this example for making a custom editable `<span>` using `ngModelController`:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#example

What I want to do now is to be able to dynamically disable editing of this field via logic inside the directive itself. By disabling it I mean the user would not be able to edit the text at all, it would just appear as regular text.

Here is a sample [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5rc6eLwSspcYcevzejHS):

Code from plunkr:

```
angular.module('app', [])


.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.stuff = "test";
  })
  .directive('contenteditable',
    function ($log) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModel) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(ngModel)) {
                    $log.warn('ngModel is not defined');
                    return;
                }
                function read() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue($element.text());
                }
                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    $element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
                };
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to dynamically affect it? With a true/false flag somewhere on the parent controller?

Comment: Please see my answer. I missed something super obvious! http://stackoverflow.com/a/31849962/1091665

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to a very helpful person in the gitter.im room for AngularJS, I realized that `contentEditable` is an actual html5 api and this is what is making the span element editable, NOT AngularJS.

All I have to do is change the name of the directive and remove `contentEditable` dynamically.